# Build and publish test classes with gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

We have a multiproject gradle repository with several subprojects. One of the subprojects is supposed to generate separate testJar and publish it to the local maven repository:

```kotlin
// build a repositories-testJar.jar with test classes for services tests
tasks.register<Jar>("testJar") {
    archiveClassifier.set("testJar")
    from(sourceSets["test"].output)
}

// the testJar must be built within the build phase
tasks.build {
    dependsOn(tasks.withType<Jar>())
}

// needed for publishing plugin to be aware of the testJar
configurations.create("testJar") {
    extendsFrom(configurations["testCompile"])
}

artifacts {
    add("testJar", tasks.named<Jar>("testJar"))
}
```

This works and I can see `-testJar.jar` is generated within the `/build/libs`.

Then, within the rootProject gradle.kts we set up a publishing extension:

```kotlin
allprojects {
    configure<PublishingExtension> {
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>(project.name) {
                groupId = "foo.bar"
                artifactId = project.name.toLowerCase().replace(":", "-")
                version = "ci"
                from(components["kotlin"])
            }
        }

        repositories {
            maven {
                url = uri("file://${rootProject.rootDir}/../m2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This also normally works and I can see modules being published in the `m2` directory. However the `testJar` is not published. I couldn't find a way how to attach the `testJar` artifact to the publication defined in root project.

Comment: Does the subproject use both the  `main` and the `test` source set? If not, have you considered just moving the source files to `main` and get rid of all the custom configuration? Or using [test fixtures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#publishing_test_fixtures)? (The reason your `testJar` artifact is not published, btw, is probably because the _component_ called `kotlin` does not know about it).

Comment: Yes it uses both – The reason for separation is that I don't want to include the `test` source set in the output build. `is probably because the component called` – that is how I understand it as well – however I couldn't manage to tell it to use it. I guess I must somehow past the link to the testJar artifact, but not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with addition of:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>(project.name + "-" + testArtifact.name) {
            groupId = "my.group"
            artifactId = project.name.toLowerCase().replace(":", "-")
            version = "version"
            artifact(testArtifact)
        }
    }
}
```